# Show the product rule is satisfied for the pointwise product $h=fg$, $f:\Bbb{R}^n\to \Bbb{R}$, $g:\Bbb{R}^n\to \Bbb{R}^m$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Show the product rule is satisfied for $h=fg$, $f:\Bbb{R}^n\to \Bbb{R}$, $g:\Bbb{R}^n\to \Bbb{R}^m$.

I am quite confused, again, as I am not sure what to exactly present. I assume I am expected to use the differential map. Can I assume $fg$ is differentiable? Can I assume $f,g$ are? Assuming all are differentiable, I can simply use the matrix of partial derivatives, but if I may not, I can't see how it is derived. I could use some guidance.

Comment: I don't see what to do here since the dimensions do not fit. Neither $f'g$ nor $gf'$ make sense since $f'\in\mathbb R^n$ and $g\in\mathbb R^m$.

Comment: It was a question written by my professor and I wouldn't rush to believe it is an invalid expression, maybe I have been remiss in stating the question correctly or there is a misunderstanding... I will check it again, however.

Comment: That is a "pointwise" product.

Comment: Ok, you have $(fg)' = g\otimes f' + fg'$, where $\otimes$ is the Kronecker product.

Comment: It really is a product. I don't see how one shows the product rule holds for a composition...

Comment: Ah, I see. So, then $fg$ is just the product of a scalar function and a vector-valued function and Doug M's answer is right, although it could probably be written better. Instead of $\partial/\partial x_1$ you could write any $\partial / \partial x_j$ or simply $\nabla$.The result on both sides is an $n\times m$ matrix of partial derivatives that represents the differential.

Comment: In it's most general form, the product rule for the derivative is $D(fg)=f\cdot Dg+g\cdot Df$. In this case, you can view $Df$ and $Dg$ as matrices of partial derivatives, the dimensions should match if you write the products on the right-hand side in the correct order. (unlike the case of 1-variable, here we are dealing with matrix multiplication, which is not commutative, so order matters!)

Comment: @FP what are you talking about? $f': \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^{1\times n}$, and $g': \Bbb R^n\to \Bbb R^{m\times n}$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Correct. And how would you want to multiply $f'\in\mathbb R^n$ and $g\in\mathbb R^m$? As I showed: you have to use the Kronecker product.

Comment: @FP it is not the Kronecker product; it is a matrix product. The "outer product", if you will.  Note that $f' \in \Bbb R^{n \times 1}$ while $g \in \Bbb R^{1 \times m}$.

Answer (score 1):

$$
D(fg) = D\begin{pmatrix}fg_1\\\vdots\\fg_m\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}D(fg_1)\\\vdots\\D(fg_m)\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}g_1f' + fg_1'\\\vdots\\g_mf' + fg_m'\end{pmatrix} = g\otimes f' + fg'.
$$

Answer (score 0):

$f(x_1,...x_n) = f$

$g(x_1,...x_n) = (g_1,...g_m)$

$fg = (fg_1, fg_2,...fg_m)$

$\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}$ fg = ($\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}fg_1, ...\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}fg_m)$

($\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}g_1 +f\frac{\partial g_1}{\partial x_1}, ...\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}g_m + f\frac{\partial g_m}{\partial x_1} )$

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1} g + f \frac{\partial g}{\partial x_1}$

Answer (score 0):

Note that we don't have a composition of ${\bf g}$ with $f$, but the locally variable scaling of the function ${\bf g}$ with the scalar "intensity" $f$.

Let ${\bf g}=(g_1,\ldots, g_m)$, ${\bf h}=(h_1,\ldots, h_m)$. Then $h_i=f\>g_i$ $(1\leq i\leq m)$ and 
$$h_{i.k}=f_{.k}\> g_i+ f\>g_{i.k}\qquad(1\leq i\leq m, \ 1\leq k\leq n)\ ,$$
according to the product ruele for differentiating a real-valued function $h_i$ with respect to the variable $x_k$. You can write this "coordinate free" as
$$d{\bf h}({\bf p}).{\bf X}=\bigl(\nabla f(p)\cdot {\bf X}\bigl) {\bf g}({\bf p})+f({\bf p})\>d{\bf g}({\bf p}).{\bf X}$$
and have therewith proven a product rule designed exactly for your problem.